# Add an expiration date to WooCommerce orders based on order items count

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, orders

I am trying to set expiration date functionality to my WooCommerce shop.

What I need is an automated system which sets an expiration date to the orders. The expiration date will be 15 days for 1 product, 30 days if you ordered 2, and so on. Basically, *expiration_days = order_quantity * 15*, and set the date in the order data.

Then, I will need expired orders to be deleted from the orders list in WooCommerce panel.

I have seen similar solutions using hooks, but I don't know how to set the expiration date as metadata. I am stuck here:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'add_expiration' );
function add_expiration( $order ) {

    // Calculate expiration date. 
    // I know how to work with dates, but I haven't found how to get quantity from the order to do the multiply.

    $order->update_meta_data('expiration_date', $expiration_date);
}
```

Then I will need just a system which checks if current date is less or not than de expiration date. Do not know if I can trigger a check fuction daily using *functions.php* too, or I need another aproach.

```
// Daily trigger
function delete_expired( ) {

    // for each order
        // if order.expiration_date > current_date
            // wp_delete_post(order);
}
```

Hope I explained it well.

Comment: Please don’t give us “I’m stuck”, and then expect us to do the work, or explain basic stuff in detail for you. How to `// Calculate expiration date` is something you should be able to easily research on your own. Do that, make an attempt, report back here with what you got.

Comment: _“Do not know if I can trigger a check fuction daily using functions.php too, or I need another aproach.”_ - go look into https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/cron/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still get cart items count that will allow to make your calculation and set an expiration date:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'add_expiration' );
function add_expiration( $order, $data ) {
    $items_count  = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    $order->update_meta_data('expiration_date', date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime( '+'. ( $items_count * 15 ) .' days' ) ) );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Now you can use **[Action Scheduler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/action-scheduler/)** plugin, to make a job queue based on that expiration date.

Action Scheduler is a scalable, traceable job queue for background processing…
Note that [Action Scheduler library](https://github.com/woocommerce/action-scheduler) is included / used by *WooCommerce* and *WooCommerce Subscriptions*.
The documentation (and examples usage) is on [ActionScheduler.org](https://actionscheduler.org/)

Action Scheduler is much more easy, efficient and scalable than WordPress Cron.

*Note that the rule in StackOverFlow is one question at the time.*